# How to prevent scrolling until a CSS animation is completed

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-5

I am working on a web project where I am starting off my page load with a full page div that animates with a fade-out animation using CSS. I am using a bootstrap spinner to display a loading image on top of the full page div, and I want to disable scrolling until the animation is completed. I know there's probably more elegant ways of coding this, but I am working on this project for a class where we are implementing bootstrap as much as possible, so I want to go this route for this reason. This is the basic solution that I came up with, but it doesn't seem to work.

HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="loadingScreen" class="loadingScreen fade-out d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="spinner spinner-grow" role="status">
      <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.loadingScreen {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #532146;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 101;
}
```

JS

```
const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
const loadingScreen = document.getElementById('loadingScreen');

window.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
    body[0].style.setProperty('overflow-y', 'visible');
    loadingScreen.remove();
    }, 6000);
});
```

I got the overflow property removed, but the getElementById() keeps returning null. Any ideas?

Comment: You mention wanting to disable scrolling until the animation is complete, but then mention including the spinner while the images are loaded. If you want to wait for the images to load, try the window load event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

Comment: 1. Typo in getElementByTagName(): The correct method name is getElement`s`ByTagName(). 2. Typo in getElementByID(): The correct method name is getElementByI`d`()

Comment: I actually just edited the post to correct the typos. I'm still find a null return value.